# CoreData database is not shown on Editor and gives an Error

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I work on CoreData and use Core Data Editor for tracking datas. But sometimes I dont see the database in the Core Data Editor and I get this error **"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134140 "Persistent store migration failed, missing mapping model." ... "** . After a while I see the database on Editor and complier doesnt give an error.

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are changing Entities &checking. One you do, delete App & Install.

Than check

You also need to create new entity after modification, if its not automatic.

See if it helps

Comment: You are right. I added new entity and entitiy's codegen is "Manuel/None" . I deleted and reinstalled , it works. But i wanna ask a question . After I release the first version of app , maybe I will want to add new entity to this app . Will I get this error  again ?

Comment: Than you have to add new Version of Core Data. There are also migration types, you can see these, like lightweight migration in core data.